# Bash function always ignores the else block

Tags: bash

When I run the below code with exact two arguments, the else block doesn't get executed.

If I take out the if else block out of the function, everything works fine.

```
#!/bin/bash
usage() {

if [[ $# -gt 2 || $# -lt 2 ]]; then
        echo "insufficient args"
else
        if [[ $# -eq 2 ]]; then
                echo "continuing with the script"
        fi
fi

}

usage
```

Comment: The problem is that usage is receiving 0 arguments.  Call usage with: `usage $@`

Comment: @Peter Ho  Thank you! That was it.

Comment: No problem! If you could accept my answer, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Use `usage "$@"`, not `usage $@`. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes#When_Should_You_Quote.3F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation, the function `usage` is receiving 0 arguments from the call.

Change the call to `usage $@`, which will pass the command line arguments to the usage function.

```
#!/bin/bash
usage() {

if [[ $# -gt 2 || $# -lt 2 ]]; then
        echo "insufficient args"
else
        if [[ $# -eq 2 ]]; then
                echo "continuing with the script"
        fi
fi

}

usage "$@"
```

Comment: You should always quote arrays, including `$@`. So this should be `usage "$@"`, not `usage $@`.